# React-Redux Infinite loop because of possibly changing state

Tags: javascript, react-redux

Good afternoon,

In my class PageList I want to add a function that changes the state on click. However when I insert this function into the a button that doesnt even get clicked the browser starts a never ending loop changing the state of currentpage.

Even though I have read the docs about components this seems strange behaviour. The behaviour accurs when addPage button is clicked.

Thanks in advance!

PageList:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Page from '../components/Page.jsx';
import {addPage} from '../actions/addPage.js'
import {nextPage} from '../actions/nextPage.js'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import _ from 'lodash';

class PageList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentpage : 0,
    };
  }

  nextPage(){
    this.setState({currentpage: this.state.currentpage+1});
  }

  renderList() {
    if(this.props.item){
      return (
        <div>
          <RaisedButton label="Next Page" onClick={this.nextPage()}></RaisedButton>
          <Page key={this.state.currentpage} index={this.state.currentpage}>
            {this.props.item.title}
            {this.props.item.desc}
          </Page>
        </div>
      );
    }else{
      return(
        <p>No Pages</p>
      )
    }
  }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <RaisedButton label="Add new Page" onClick={() => this.props.addPage("Titel Page", "Page Beschrijving")}></RaisedButton>
            <ul>
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

// Get apps state and pass it as props to PageList
//      > whenever state changes, the PageList will automatically re-render
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        pageList: state.pageList,
        item: _.find(state.pages, 'id', ownProps.currentpage)
    };
}

// Get actions and pass them as props to to PageList
//      > now PageList has this.props.selectPage
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({addPage: addPage, nextPage: nextPage}, dispatch);
}

// We don't want to return the plain PageList (component) anymore, we want to return the smart Container
//      > PageList is now aware of state and actions
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(PageList);
```

Comment: Thanks thats a good read, I was wondering why this happened, unfortutely I kept overlooking the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the `nextPage` function on each render instead of passing it to onClick.

Change `onClick={this.nextPage()}` with `onClick={() => this.nextPage()}`

Comment: OH thanks so much! I just noticed that I can also use onClick={this.nextPage}. Thats what I used earlier but I didnt notice it was without these:  '()'

Answer (score 0):

There is a little error:

```
 <RaisedButton label="Next Page" onClick={this.nextPage}>
 </RaisedButton>
```

otherwise this.nextPage() is called right when it is rendered.